# Using PHP SESSIONS in an API environment

Tags: php, cordova, session, slim, api-design

I have built a cordova mobile application that uses slim framwork to create API's to communciate with my database.

The last step before I finish the project is properly setting up SESSIONS so that a users data is transfered between pages.

At the moment, I have manually set up the session id so it creates one SESSION file in the tmp directory to be accessed. It works fine however this isn't ideal as i wish to have multiple users accessing the app at one time.

Now I'm very unfamilair with how both PHP sessions work and how Slim uses SESSIONS so any help given needs to be in laymans terms.

I have heard about using middleware but again I'm not sure how to use or even install it. Essentially, i just want to be able to carry on using the PHP native SESSIONs i have in place but allow for multiple users to have their own SESSION file.

Currently, I have session_id('TEST) and session_start() in every API function thats being called and this works fine. If i were to take away the session_id and let the application creates sessions for me, every time a API is called, a new session file is being created with a long file name.

Here is my setup and an example of my issue:

[image]

[image]

Above is what happens when I remove the manual session_id('TEST)

[image]

It may be something very simple for you guys so I'm sorry. This is the last step of my work so any assistance with this will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to your problem, but you AFAIK you only need to define `session_start();` one time, at the start of the file before you start using sessions.

Comment: So you are most likely not passing the session id along all the way … but where exactly you didn’t handle that properly, is rather impossible to tell with what little info we got.

Comment: @CBroe at the start of every API function is session_start and session_is(TEST) so its being passed fine when I'm only using one session file but its when I take that away and let PHP sort the session is when it creates multiple files....

Comment: PHP native sessions utilize cookies by default to pass the session ID.  That's not an option for you here.  Do a search on "cordova app php session" or "cordova app session cookies" for some related reading that could get you started in the right direction.  You're not the first to want to do this, so there's material out there to consult.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for this Patrick. So do you think cookies is the way to go for this application?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you _can't_ use cookies with a Cordova app, and therefore need to find a workaround.